# Possible to use a Visio page as a layer on another page?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

Is it possible to use a page in a Visio doc as a layer in another page in the same doc?

Currently, I'm copying and pasting when I make changes to page 1 into a layer on page 2, but would like it if the layer simply updated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Background pages can be used in this manner.

Create a page ("Page 2") and in the **Page Setup** dialog in the **Page Properties** tab set the **Type** to **Background**

[image]

Then in "Page 1" in the **Page Setup** dialog in the **Page Properties** tab set the **Background** to **Page 2**

[image]

Now everything you draw on page 2  will automatically show up on page 1 - underneath any shapes in page 1.

Comment: Perfect! Any way to set the transparency of the background page now?

Comment: Not in a direct way. There's no overall transparency setting for a page. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you could simulate the effect. A background page can have its own background page: fgpage -> bgpage1 -> bgpage2. You could draw a rectangle on bgpage1 and set the transparency of that shape so that it would obsure or reveal what was on bgpage2 as needed.